# How can I update the price when someone enters postcode or zip code in woocommerce checkout page?

Tags: php, plugin-development, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

So, I am working with my custom plugin in which I need to get zip code or postcode on woocommerce checkout page and add my additional price and be done with the payment.
I tried using AJAX, which get the zip code and add my price into it and update the price.

```
/**
Here my AJAX Call
**/
global $woocommerce;
//$additional_amount is coming dynamically via an external API
$additional_amount = 5.00; // can vary depending upon zip code
number_format((float)$additional_amount, 2, '.', '');
$woocommerce->cart->set_total($woocommerce->cart->total + $additional_amount);
```

Then I send this total to my AJAX call back like below:

```
$arr['amount'] = $woocommerce->cart->get_total();
echo json_encode($arr);exit();
```

It shows me updated price but when I do payment process using stripe or any other payment gateway, it charges my the old price.

I also tried it this way

```
$fee = 5.00;
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Handling', $fee, true, 'standard' );
```

But it also does not work.
Is there a way to do add my additional price into checkout amount using AJAX or any other way.
I am using Wordpress 5.4 and Woocommerce version 4.0.1

Comment: Shouldn’t this just be set up as the shipping price? Why are you doing this with code?

Comment: Well, this is not about shipping address, I have an API which sends me Tax information according to zip code and there is no place in the backend to add this API in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

As I was trying to add some additional amount to my charge and I was unable to update the charge amount. The code which I was trying was this using AJAX call:

```
$woocommerce->cart->set_total($woocommerce->cart->total + $additional_amount);
```

But the real problem was with my payment method, not the cart price. So, I resolved it using a filter which happens just before charge amount is about to sent to database and payment gateway.
The code which works for me is this:

```
function additional_amount($order){
    $total_additional_amount = $amount1 + $amount 2;
    $total_additional_amount = round($total_additional_amount, 2);
    $order->set_total( $total_amount);
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'additional_amount', 10, 1 );
```

Using this filter, I was able to update the actual charge amount.
I hope that will help to someone.